# Error when Passing string values from Python request to PHP

Tags: php, python

**What I am Trying to do**

What I am attempting to do is, pass values from my python application to my web api where it gets saved to my database.

**The problem**

The reason why I am posting is because, I can send integers, 1,2,3 to my database from my python and that saves fine. But If I send "test","ape","tree" nothing is placed in the database. (PS, the data type is varchar(6) )

I can also pass string into the database (using post) from the browser and it works.

**What have done**

I have created my API , database and python script that passes the data around.

Python.

```
import requests
load={'par':'ape12'} //This doesnt save "ape" to the database
#load={'par':'3'} //This saves "3" to the database
r=requests.post("http://my-server.com/load.php",data=load)
```

PHP

```
<?php
//Connect to DB
include ("connectDB.php");
$loadgot=$_POST['load'];

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO detect(l_result) 
VALUES ($loadgot)");

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Hoping someone could assist me in this regard.

Thank you

Comment: Try  to modify the `'ape12'` to `"'ape12'"`

Comment: @mkHun Oh;...That was it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a properly formed query to mysql. The value needs to be surrounded by quotes, but also needs to escape any characters which will break out from the quoted environment. In practice, the best solution these days is to use parametrised queries (see [example](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)) like:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO detect(l_result) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $loadgot);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Or if you really want to use text query (you really shouldn't), you can do:

```
$loadgot_safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $loadgot);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO detect(l_result) VALUES ('$loadgot_safe')");
```

The reason why you *MUST NOT* use:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO detect(l_result) VALUES ('$loadgot')");
```

is that anyone can submit multiple values - for example `value1'), ('value2` will expand to `INSERT INTO detect(l_result) VALUES ('value1'), ('value2')` - which is definitely not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Modify the `'ape12'` to  `"'ape12'"`.

Because, in MySQL we give the query like this

`INSERT INTO detect(l_result) VALUES 'Value1';`

So pass the values to MySQL with quotes. But no need for the integers.

From @e4c5 comment. Users wont give the quotes while entering the input. So we ensure the query inside the script. So try to changed the code like this

`mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO detect(l_result) VALUES ('$loadgot')");`

Comment: While this certainly works this is not the solution. It's wrong to expect the users to send the data properly quoted. It's the programmers responsibility to ensure that it is so. You could do mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO detect(l_result) 
VALUES ('$loadgot')"); but this is still wrong! This and the accepted answer both leave you open to sql injection.

Comment: This is still a bad answer. Don't ever embed variables in the query string. You should use either escaping (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or just parametrised queries (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: @viraptor `$loadgot` variable is placed within a double quote. So the variable will interpolate. I cann't understand what is the problem.?

Comment: think what happens if `$loadgot` contains `value'), ('and'), ('another`. You can read more at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection

Comment: @viraptor I'm not ever work with PHP. And i have the little bit of knowledge in MySQL. So the reason i cann't follow you. Thank you.  :)